# Table conflict with SQL request

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables [structure] :

- "medias" to store pictures [id, creatorID (user who create the media), date]
- "likes" to store likes on pictures [id, senderID (user who liked), mediaID (media liked)]
- "comments" to store comments on pictures [id, mediaID (media commented)]
- "follow" to store a follow [id, follow (user X), following (one following of the user X)]
- "users" to store users [id]

All tables are made with an ID which increment at insert.

Here my request to display a flux of pictures for an user :

```
SELECT 
 m.id as mediaID, 
 COUNT(l.id) as likesCount, 
 COUNT(c.id) as commentsCount 
FROM medias m 
INNER JOIN follow f 
 ON f.follow = 'user_here' AND m.creatorID = f.following AND m.date < 'timestamp_here' 
INNER JOIN users u 
 ON u.id = m.creatorID 
LEFT JOIN likes x 
 ON m.id = x.mediaID AND x.senderID = 2 
LEFT JOIN likes l 
 ON m.id = l.mediaID 
LEFT JOIN comments c 
 ON m.id = c.mediaID 
GROUP BY m.id
```

When there's more than 1 comment, likesCount take the value of the commentsCount. And when I dislike a picture, the commentCount decrement of 1 comment. So, I really don't know how can I solve it...

Comment: how would you know if a user has disliked the photo? because your logic only states if a user has liked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to solve your problem is to use `distinct`:

```
SELECT m.id as mediaID, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) as likesCount, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as commentsCount
```

If you have lots of likes and comments, a better way may be to aggregate before joining or use a correlated subquery.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I didn't know this command and it's very useful in this case. You made my day!